# How to execute .bat file with batch parameters

Tags: ruby, batch-file, parameters, arguments

I am trying to execute a .bat file with Ruby using:

```
System("path\to\.bat")
```

However, I would like to pass parameters to this file. Is this possible?

Comment: Don't use `"path\to"`. It's not generating what you think it is. "\t" is a tab, not a path delimiter. Instead use single quotes `'path\to'` which will generate a literal backslash + `t`. Read the IO documentation also; You don't have to use backslashes with path names at all, avoiding the problem completely. Also, how to call sub-shells and executables is nicely covered by the documentation and in questions on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass them as you would do it normally.

```
`path\to\.bat -some=flag another-way`
```